# Facebook login : Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The “state” param from the URL and session do not match

Tags: php, facebook

i have an error with the facelogin api after uploading my webapp to live it gives me this error **Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match**

i have turn the the project to live and update my redirect urls as follow: here is my code :

```
<?php 
require_once("../Admin/include/sessions.php");
require_once("../Admin/include/Function.php");
require_once("databaseCon.php");

?>

<?php 
//startSession

//session_start();
require'vendor/autoload.php';
$fb=new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'=>'579253476335258',
 'app_secret'=>'77b43e9b8d1898020acb08fb4a993'
    ,'default_graph_version'=>'v2.7']);
$helper=$fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email'];
$LoginUrl=$helper->getLoginUrl("https://curvaegypt.com/En/fb-init.php",$permissions);
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['accesstoken']=(string)$accessToken;

} catch(Facebook\Exception\ResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exception\SDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['accesstoken'])){
 try{
     $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['accesstoken']);
     //,gender,birthday,link
    $res=$fb->get("/me?fields=id,first_name,name,email");
    $resimage=$fb->get("/me/picture?redirect=false&width=250&hieght=250");
    $user=$res->getGraphUser();
    $userimage=$resimage->getGraphUser();
   $id= $user->getField('id');
   $name= $user->getField('name');
   $email= $user->getField('email');
  // $link= $user->getLink();
   $userData = $res->getDecodedBody();
   //$bday=$userData['birthday'];
    //$gender=$user->getField('gender'); 
     $user_image=$userimage['url'];

     $date=strtotime($bday);
            $birthdate=date('Y-m-d',$date);

      $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE account_id=?");
       $stmt->execute(array($id));
      $count=$stmt->rowCount();
    if($count >0){
        $row=$stmt->fetch();
        $_SESSION ["client_id"] = $row[0];
        Redirect_to("index.php");
    }else{$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO clients (account_id,fullname,email,image) 
    values (:userid,:name,:email,:image)");
       $stmt->execute(array('userid'=>$id,
                           'name'=>$name,
                            'email'=>$email,
                            //'date'=>$birthdate,
                           //'gender'=>$gender,
                           'image'=>$user_image
                           //'link'=>$link
                           ));

    //get last inserted
    $rowid = $conn->lastInsertId();
          if($stmt->rowCount() >0){ $_SESSION['client_id']=$id;      
       Redirect_to("index.php");
         }else{$_SESSION['client_id']=$id;
            Redirect_to("index.php"); 
              }
         }



   //  echo "done"."<br/>";
 }catch(Exception $e){}

}
 //echo "done"."<br/>";
?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely, your session is not working correctly. Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? The empty line between the first and second code block might already be the culprit here, that could be the output that prevents setting of the session cookie.

Comment: but it was working in my localhost without errors

Comment: array(3) {
  ["FBRLH_state"]=>
  string(32) "79ef8453694ab79e2c5d5a5fae874f01"
  ["accesstoken"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["accesstokencreat"]=>
  string(8) "sessionm"
}

Comment: afer trying some test it appeares that the access token is not ceating anything as it 's always empty i tried to set it with the testuser accestoken from the facebook developer page and worked

Comment: Just noticing that you exposed your app secret in the code above, so you need to go and reset that via your app dashboard first of all now. (Otherwise, anyone reading this here now has a valid app access token for your app.)